# Gateway + ServiceActivator without poller

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I like the way SI allows for making transparent proxies to channels using `@Gateway` and `@ServiceActivator`.

I was looking at http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-interfaces-subscribablechannel. There are two types of channels:

- Pollable (Queue, Priority, Rendezvous)
- Subscribable (Direct, Executor, PublishSubscribe)

Looking at these, it looks to me that all of these are made so that one of the below is true:

- The receiver polls
- The sender blocks
- The messages can be processed by multiple threads at once

Is there a way to configure / use SI in a way that:

- Sender sends to a queue and does not block (unless obviously the queue is full)
- Receiver takes from the queue, but does not poll

Pretty much like `put` / `take` from [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) from Java itself.

Am I overlooking some constraint here? Also, if there are other alternatives in Spring for what I'm trying to do (basically asynchronous event bus) with a similar interface (i.e. not having to manually send messages, but having it in a transparent way using interfaces), I'd be glad to hear about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `QueueChannel` and set the Poller's `receiveTimeout` to -1, the framework will do what you want - the poller thread will block on the `receive()` waiting for a message (with a negative timeout, it uses `take()` under the covers).

By default (for a polling consumer) the `max-messages-per-poll` is also -1 (infinity) which means there will be no "polling" at all (after the first trigger), just blocking.

If the queue has a limit, the sender will block until there's space (it uses `put()` when a send timeout of -1 is used - the default).